# Multipart upload to s3 with presigned urls from Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, retrofit2, multipart, pre-signed-url

We are trying to implement a mechanism to make **multipart uploads directly to s3 using presigned URLs from android**.

There are multiple guides that explain the method, for example:

- JS: https://www.altostra.com/blog/multipart-uploads-with-s3-presigned-url
- Python: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2305#issuecomment-591128376

Following this guide, we managed to make everything work **other than making a stable and robust upload process from android**.
We can directly translate the client part from JS/Python to Java/Kotlin of course.
However, we wish to use a library such as Retrofit2 (or another) to make sure it supports proper multipart upload functionalities, such as auto retries, unstable network recoveries, etc.

Retrofit2 for example has a multipart option, but it uses only one endpoint url - whereas here we have to generate a presigned url for each part, and also make another request for finishing the multipart.

Is there an example, guide or any other best practice suggestion to handle the client side of multipart uploads to s3 with presigned urls from Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making the pre-signed url part of the request with the `@Url` annotation on your Retrofit interface with a param, like this:

```
@PUT
suspend fun uploadFile(@Url url: String, @Body file: RequestBody): Response<Unit>
```